# Что такое нормированное пространство?

Tags: математика, терминология

Я прочитал википедию, и немогу понять что такое нормированное пространство.
Я только понял что есть векторное пространство и она находиться над каким-то полем которому мы дали норму.

И что значит эта формула?
[image: формула]

Comment: В формуле ошибка: вокруг `x_i` должен быть модуль. `x_i` здесь i-ая координата вектора `x` для которого вычисляется норма.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Математика изучает всякие кунштюки. Для этих кунштюков определяют самые разные свойства, а потом радостно восклицают: "Вот это кунштюк"!

Для довольно многих кунштюков в математике придумывают правила сложения и умножения на число. Это не только числа. Это и углы, и вектора, и корни из отрицательных чисел, и функции, и, страшно сказать, билинейные отображения и вообще тензоры.

Мало того, для некоторых из этих кунштюков до кучи придумывают понятие "размер". Почесав репы, Гаусс с Банахом решили, что не всякий размер подходит для измерения кунштюков. Размер становится размером, если (а) у пустого кунштюка размер ноль, если (б) размер кунштюка, увеличенного в десять раз, равен десяти размерам исходного кунштюка, и ещё требуется, (в) чтобы размер суммы двух кунштюков был не больше чем сумма размеров каждого из складываемых кунштюков.

В школьной математике мы встречаемся всего с несколькими видами кунштюков: целые числа, дроби, вещественные числа, вектора, - для которых определены операция сложения, умножения на число и измерение размера.

Для чисел это модуль числа - насколько число далеко от нуля.

Для векторов - квадратный корень из суммы квадратов координат, евклидово расстояние от нуля.

Вот, наверное, и всё, что есть измеримого из школьных кунштюков. Но математики не ограничены школьным учебником. Они выдумывают всё новые и новые виды кунштюков. Или способов измерения уже существующих.

Например, для измерения размера отрезка не обязательно ограничивать себя квадратами. Можно извлекать четвёртые степени из суммы четвёртых степеней координат. Можно сотые степени из суммы сотых степеней. Да можно вообще не извлекать корни, а просто взять и сложить модули всех координат. И это тоже можно использовать как размер вектора. Зачем такие страсти выдумывать, когда есть простое и понятное геометрически наглядное и линейкой измеримое расстояние между двумя точками в привычном нам пространстве? А для полноты! Это такое заклинание, которое произносят математики, начиная извращать уже привычные и понятные концепции. Иногда это заводит их так далеко, что внезапно оказывается необыкновенно полезно.

С векторами это не шибко полезно, а вот с функциями... Как можно задать размер функции? Например, можно взять максимальное значение модуля функции на области определения. А можно взять интеграл от квадрата функции по области определения. А можно ещё как нибудь извратиться - например, для многочлена в качестве размера взять максимальную ненулевую степень. Всё это будет укладываться в требования, которые Банах и Гаусс предъявили к концепции "размер кунштюка".

И тут вдруг может выясниться, что куча теорем, которые доказали в алгебре, геометрии, математическом анализе для чисел и векторов можно практически без изменений перенести на совершенно другие кунштюки. Достаточно сформулировать расстояние между двумя кунштюками как размер разности двух кунштюков.

И тогда можно почти без усилий построить функциональный анализ. Сходимость функций - равномерная и в среднем. Разложение в функциональные ряды (привет рядам Фурье).  Решение функциональных уравнений и вычисление функций от матриц (линейных операторов). Даже алгоритм деления многочленов внезапно становится алгоритмом деления Евклида для чисел, ну почти.

И ладно бы всё это было пустым теоретизированием. Функциональные ряды - изображения JPEG. Преобразование Фурье и вейвлет-преобразования - основа современных методов анализа сигналов. Теория оптимизации так вовсе состоит из размеров чуть менее чем полностью: размеры функторов, размеры кунштюков, размеры операторов - сплошные размеры, которые надо привести к нулю.

Только нельзя в математике называть кунштюки кунштюками и меряться размерами. Всё должно быть возвышенно и благообразно. Каждый вид кунштюков получил имя собственное, а размер назвали **нормой**.

**Нормированное пространство** - это тип кунштюков и определенный для них размер. Например [пространство квадратично интегрируемых функций](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)) - совокупность функций таких, что интеграл от квадрата значения функции на отрезке (или даже на всей прямой) существует. Для таких функций  <del>размер</del> норма задаётся как квадратный корень из того самого интеграла

Итак, норма в математике - это группа понятий, которые сходны в одном: они задают размер объекта.

- Норма нулевого (или пустого) объекта должна быть равна нулю.
- Норма увеличенного объекта должна быть во столько же раз больше нормы исходного объекта.
- Норма суммы двух объектов должна быть не больше суммы норм каждого из объектов.

Как-то так.

Answer (score 3):

Я попробую объяснить чуть чуть проще, чем в википедии.

В общем то, ключевая фраза, на которую надо обратить внимание: "норма является естественным обобщением понятия длины вектора в евклидовом пространстве"

Формула интересна тем, что в ней есть два параметра - n (размерность пространства) и p.

Для **p=2** получаем обычную, привычную нам длину вектора:

для случая n=2 мы получаем формулу для длины вектора на плоскости: `sqrt(X*X + Y*Y)`, где вектор - это (X, Y).

Для трехмерного пространства это `sqrt(X*X +Y*Y + Z*Z)`, для вектора (X,Y,Z) то есть, квадратный корень из суммы квадратов каждой из координат.

Но вполне себе имеет физически смысл и "норма" при **р=1**: это просто сумма координат вектора: x+y для двухмерного случая, и x+y+z для трехмерного случая.

Дальше - при увеличении p - я не вижу в формуле понятного физического смысла, но готов поверить, что правила для нормы, описанные на странице в википедии, выполняются и для p>2.

И еще одно маленькое замечание: есть такое выражение "математические рассуждения - это набор тавтологий". Фактически, определение сводится к фразе "нормированное пространство - это пространство, на котором введена норма". Всё остальное - это уточнение - что такое норма, каким правилам она подчиняется и как связана с метрикой.

Comment: А в этой формуле x(i) указывает на вектор в этом пространстве?

Comment: Как я понимаю, x(i) указывает на i-ю координату вектора в этом пространстве

Comment: Я бы говорил о компоненте, а не координате вектора..

Comment: Я думал что формула нужна для расчёта длины векторов в векторном пространстве, а вот например у меня есть вектор в обычном пространстве 2d, у котрого начало в точке 0;0 а конец в [3,7],  тогда как обработает эта формула данный простой пример, и (n) будет равно 1?

Comment: Почему n=1??? В двумерном пространстве n=2, оно ж двумерное.

Comment: Тогда что делает эта формула?

Comment: Что она считает?

Comment: В двумерном простарнстве при p=2 формула посчитает классическую длинну вектора sqrt(3*3+7*7). При p=1 формула посчитает НОРМУ вектора, сумму модулей его кординат (равную 10 = 3+7). Когда это бывает нужно? Представьте себе, что у вас задача - грубо отделить "длинные" и "короткие" векторы. Вот тогда нет смысла считаь все эти квадраты, корни - достаточно посмотреть, вообще координаты "здровые" или "так себе"

Comment: Окей а если p = 2, и есть 3 вектора, то эта формула посчитает суммы этих 3 длин векторов?,

Comment: Формула предназанчена для подсчета нормы одного вектора. Можно предварительно сложить векторы и посчитать норму вектора, являющегося суммой.

Comment: Ну вообщем норма предназначена для нахождение длины 1 вектора, её обозначение ||x||, а с формулу x(i) указывают на кординаты, если p = 2,  то x(i)  будет обработан 2 раза и отдаст значение вектора  по оси OX, и по оси oy? Если p = 3 то добавиться ещё oz.  Так работает норма?

Comment: При p=1 получается обычное т.н. "[Манхеттенское расстояние](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)"

Comment: > "Если p = 3 то добавиться ещё oz" - нет. Ось z добавится в том случае, если n=3. p - это некий другой параметр, не размерность пространства. Это, если можно так выразиться, "выбор способа подсчета нормы" При p=1 имеем, как подсказал нам Harry, манхэттенское расстояние, при p=2 - привычную длинну вектора.

Comment: А то есть если у нас n = 3, и p = 3,  то длина формула прмед вид x*x*x + y*y*y +  z*z*z, ту  тоесть n - это типо измерение, 1d, 2d, 3d,  А p это в какую степегь возвести эти кординаты. Например если n = 1, и p = 1,   то будет просто x?

Comment: > А то есть если у нас n = 3, и p = 3 - да, именно так. Физического смысла при р>2 я придумать не могу :-)

Comment: Ну тогда спасибо, что помогли